# Point-to-site clients can see VM's in Virtual Network but cannot access site-to-site resources

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

We've got an existing Virtual Network in Azure, with a site-to-site connection to a 3rd party (X).

An Ubuntu VM is deployed in the network, and can ping/access all resources hosted by X through the site-to-site connection.

I have configured an Azure Certificate point-to-site, downloaded the VPN client, and successfully connected from the client machine.

I need clients to be able to access resources hosted by X, while connected to the VPN, from their local machines; without needing to remote into the Ubuntu box mentioned above.

Over the VPN, the client can ping the Ubuntu box private IP - but cannot access the resources hosted by X

I am a networking newbie - is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you could add the route for both X and your clients.

You can type `route print` in the command prompt to find if there is a route to the 3rd party network. Also, adjust the on-premise site-to-site routing to include the Azure P2S subnet(address pool). You could read [this1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1028402/route-azure-point-to-site-traffic-to-on-premise-network-via-site-to-site-connect) and [this2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-point-to-site-routing#vnetbranchbgp) for more details.